# EF core: How do I go through a list created in a many to many relationship?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I'm new to programming and would like your help, please...
I'm creating a many to many relationship at efcore and I have these two entities:

`1. DocumentType.cs`

```
public DocumentType()
        {
            _transactionTypes = new List<DocumentTypeTransactionType>();            
        }
public int DocumentType_Id { get; set; }
public string ButtonHeader { get; set; }
private string _buttonColor;

private IList<DocumentTypeTransactionType> _transactionTypes;
public virtual IList<DocumentTypeTransactionType> TransactionTypes
        {
            get { return _transactionTypes; }
            set { _transactionTypes = value; }
        }
```

`2.TransactionType.cs`

```
public int TransactionType_Id { get; set; }
public int SortOrder { get; set; }
public string UserString { get { return Name; } }
public int SourceAccountTypeId { get; set; }
public int TargetAccountTypeId { get; set; }
public int DefaultSourceAccountId { get; set; }
public int DefaultTargetAccountId { get; set; }
public int ForeignCurrencyId { get; set; }
```

I have created an entity class to represent the join table:

`DocumentTypeTransactionType.cs`

```
public int DocumentType_Id { get; set; }
public DocumentType DocumentType { get; set; }

public int TransactionType_Id { get; set; }
public TransactionType TransactionType { get; set; }
```

`MyDbContext.cs`

```
modelBuilder.Entity<DocumentTypeTransactionType>()
  .HasKey(p => new { p.DocumentType_Id, p.TransactionType_Id });
modelBuilder.Entity<DocumentTypeTransactionType>()
  .HasOne(p => p.DocumentType)
  .WithMany(x => x.TransactionTypes)
  .HasForeignKey(p => p.DocumentType_Id);
modelBuilder.Entity<DocumentTypeTransactionType>()
  .HasOne(p => p.TransactionType)
  .WithMany()
  .HasForeignKey(p => p.TransactionType_Id);
```

My problem is this: 
I need to use the next function **GetNeededAccountTypes()** inside the `DocumentType.cs` entity that contains fields that belong to the `TransactionType.cs` entity. When the relationship is created, the `IList<DocumentTypeTransactionType>` cannot access the `TransactionType.cs` entity? Am I doing the many-to-many relationship right?

Now my `DocumentType.cs` entity would look like this:

```
public DocumentType()
        {
            _transactionTypes = new List<DocumentTypeTransactionType>();            
        }
public int DocumentType_Id { get; set; }
public string ButtonHeader { get; set; }
private string _buttonColor;

private IList<DocumentTypeTransactionType> _transactionTypes;
public virtual IList<DocumentTypeTransactionType> TransactionTypes
        {
            get { return _transactionTypes; }
            set { _transactionTypes = value; }
        }
public List<int> GetNeededAccountTypes()
        {
            var result = new List<int>();
            foreach (var accountTransactionType in TransactionTypes)
            {
                if (accountTransactionType.TargetAccountTypeId != MasterAccountTypeId &&
                    accountTransactionType.DefaultTargetAccountId == 0)
                {
                    if (!result.Contains(accountTransactionType.TargetAccountTypeId))
                        result.Add(accountTransactionType.TargetAccountTypeId);
                }
                if (accountTransactionType.SourceAccountTypeId != MasterAccountTypeId &&
                    accountTransactionType.DefaultSourceAccountId == 0)
                {
                    if (!result.Contains(accountTransactionType.SourceAccountTypeId))
                        result.Add(accountTransactionType.SourceAccountTypeId);
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Help please!

Answer (score 1):

The problems seems to be in your modelBuilder configuration. Try this:

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<DocumentTypeTransactionType>()
           .HasKey(p => new { p.DocumentType_Id, p.TransactionType_Id });
        modelBuilder.Entity<DocumentTypeTransactionType>()
          .HasOne(p => p.DocumentType)
          .WithMany(x => x.TransactionTypes)
          .HasForeignKey(p => p.DocumentType_Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<DocumentTypeTransactionType>()
          .HasOne(p => p.TransactionType)
          .WithMany(x => x.DocumentTypes)
          .HasForeignKey(p => p.TransactionType_Id);
    }
```

Hope, this answers to your question.